# Whereas + present participle

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, participles, present-participles

Is it grammatically correct to use *whereas* + a present participle?

For example:

**I am disinclined to recognize my weak mathematical skills, whereas willing to admit my lack of English skills.**

This sounds silly to me, but the reason I am asking is because this same sentence seems to work when using *while* instead of *whereas*

Same example with *while*:

**I am disinclined to recognize my weak mathematical skills, while willing to admit my lack of English skills.**

Are they both grammatically correct? Are they both incorrect? Is one correct, but not the other?

If the example with *while* is grammatically incorrect, then is the following sentence also grammatically incorrect?

**He does the dishes while singing.**

Comment: whereas I am willing to

Comment: @Lambie I understand that would make the sentence sound better, but I think you may have misunderstand the crux of my question. I'm curious as to why _whereas willing_ doesn't sound right, but _while willing_ sounds fine.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/whereas [it also applies to all Englishes]

Comment: @Lambie I'm aware that _whereas_ cannot be used to refer to time. In the second example sentence, I'm using _while_ for contrast. In the third example sentence I'm using _while_ in reference to time. None of the examples use _whereas_ to refer to time.

Comment: "I'm curious as to why *whereas willing* doesn't sound right, but *while willing* sounds fine." Most likely, it's simply because we don't say it. We can assume an omitted *I am* and it's fine. But it's simply not done. It's one of those *because* answers when it comes to idiomatic uses.

Comment: Yes, and that is explained in the dictionary link.

Comment: @JasonBassford Gotcha! I was hoping that wouldn't be the case - that instead there would be some rule that explained the difference. However, as someone new to studying English grammar, I've come to realize that often that is best answer we have for certain situations   

Anyways, thanks for the response!

Comment: @Lambie I appreciate your response in helping me get to the bottom of this, but I don't think that link moves us closer to an answer. It's good to mention, but the question doesn't involve any confusion in regards to that rule.

Comment: You're right. Your respondents aren't. Reason it's accceptable is that the unexpressed subject of the subordinate clause is the same as the subject of the main clause. However, it's clunky because of the semantics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reading, I think it is grammatically correct to use *whereas* + a non-finite participle clause - it just may not be idiomatically correct (as suggested by @JasonBassford).

One of my sources for coming to this conclusion is the Cambridge dictionary. As explained in [this article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/clauses-finite-and-non-finite):

> We often use non-finite clauses after some subordinating conjunctions
>   like *after*, *although*, *though* and *if*.

Comment: No, it isn't grammatical at all, therefore, not idiomatic.  ***whereas *** is a coordinating conjunction, not a subordinating conjunction, in your context.  You can't have subordination with whereas. It contrasts two separate ideas i.e. independent clauses. I went today whereas you went yesterday. I went yesterday yet you went today. Going to the theater is fun whereas going to the dentist is not.  That is not subordination. You can  have "while willing to admit etc. because it is subordinate.  "I am blah blah blah while willing to admit blug blug blug. That is subordination.

Comment: @Lambie You bring up an interesting point. However, every source I've seen, classifies _whereas_ as a subordinating conjunction. https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subordinate.html https://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/subcon.htm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Subordinating_conjunctions

Comment: I saw that source. Whereas is a mistake in that list.

Comment: @Lambie It's a bit hard to tell, but there are 3 sources listed there

Comment: It is not a non-finite  participial clause. This is: whereas ***being willing to admit blah blah blah*** And you might want to believe me given the content of your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hard-and-fast grammatical pattern ***taken from the language itself as a living organism*** (maybe that is going too far) that shows that ***whereas*** is not a subordinating conjunction.

- The boys played tennis and the girls played volleyball.

Everyone (I hope) will agree that the word and is a coordinating conjunction because the bits on either side of it, but not including it, can stand on their own. Can they stand on their own? Yes? Well, then the word and is what allows that.

You can substitute any of the so-called coordinating conjunctions there, remove them and you create two stand-alone utterances that are independent clauses. That is way to see how two independent clauses may be joined.

- The boys played tennis but the girls played volleyball. [coordinator:but]
- The boys played tennis. The girls played volleyball.

Now, if you use ***whereas*** instead of ***and***, the same is true as regards the sentence above.

Now take the OP's sentence:

- I am disinclined to recognize my weak mathematical skills, whereas willing to admit my lack of English skills.

> ***If you want to introduce a whereas in that sentence,*** you need to do this:
>
> - I am not willing to recognize my weak mathematical skills whereas I am willing to admit my lack of English skills. OR
> - I am disinclined to recognize my weak mathematical skills whereas I am willing to admit my lack of English skills.
> - I am disinclined to recognize my weak mathematical skills whereas I am not disinclined to admit my lack of English skills. or: not so disinclined as regards my English skills.
>
> Most grammars/grammarians ***do classify the word whereas as a
>   subordinating conjunction*** where an independent clause is joined to an
>   dependent one. However, all you need to do is see whereas used in texts,to see that the clauses used with it are not "subordinate to one another."

The word whereas in sentences contrasting "equal" utterances (subject, verb and predicate) plays a coordination role and not a subordination role. This can be seen by substituting any of the well-known coordinators such as ***but or yet*** where two clauses are coordinated, which are called coordinating words, and there is no "subordination". The kind of logic one finds with subordinating conjunctions is not the actual logic of the use of whereas (in its non-time meanings).

Here is a traditional explanation of a subordinating conjunctions, and it's pretty good too: [subordinating conjunctions](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/subordinating-conjunction.html)

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer. However, I disagree with how you arrived at classifying _whereas_ as a coordinating conjunction. In regards to your example, if we instead substitute _unless_ in place of _and_, we get the following sentence: **the boys played tennis unless the girls played volleyball.** Does this then make _unless_ a coordinating conjunction? I would say no whereas your logic would say yes. I could be wrong, but my understanding of a subordinating conjunction is that it makes the clause dependent rather than the other way around.

Comment: It seems that the crux of our disagreement is centered around whether a subordinating conjunction makes a clause dependent or whether an already dependent clause makes a conjunction subordinating. I honestly don't know which one is correct, but understanding is that a subordinating conjunction makes a clause dependent. I would be happy to be wrong though.

Comment: No, the crux of it is that "whereas willing" is not grammatical at all. In the end, it does not matter what it is called. It matters whether it is accurate. Unless willing is a noun, which it isn't, it's wrong. Nouns: Being willing to understand something is one thing whereas being hardheaded is another.  or Willingness, same thing. Willing it to be true is a pipe dream whereas willing it to be nice is not. There you go. All the grammar that's fit to use. Last thought: it surprises me that as an English speaker you can't "hear it".

Comment: Erm. What you been eating Lambie??!!# ;-) You can remove the subject and the verb BE in bith your CC examples. "I am disinclined to X, but/and willing to Y"

Comment: @Araucaria I notice that people become abusive when they disagree. If you use the "whereas", you can't do it the way you suggest:  "I am disinclined to X but ****whereas**** willing to Y" =not grammatical. Why is that contentious in any way??

Comment: @Lambie Sorry if it came accross that way. It was meant to be the exact opposite, a bit of humour (*watchu talkin about Willis*). Hence the punctuation and winking face. My point is that coordinating conjunctions famously allow for gapping parallel structure from the second coordinate. The fact that *and/but/or* will all allow this if substituted into the OP´s example, whereas *whereas* won´t, seems to rule *OUT* *whereas* from being a coordinating conjunction!

Comment: "I am disinclined to X, but/and willing to Y"=Fine; "I am disinclined to X, whereas willing to Y"= not fine. "whereas" cannot "gap a parallel structure [here] from the second coordinate". The reason the OP's example does not work is because it isn't grammatical. For "Whereas" to be a CC requires the full verb: I am disinclined to x whereas I ****am**** willing to y. And the way it is written is simply not grammatical. As written, it is not coordinating, (see my answer) and it isn't subordinating because it simply is not grammatical. The original question was grammaticality; it is not.

Comment: The second coordinate in a coordination des not have to be a full claus - it can be gapped. That`s my point.

Comment: You keep switching back and forth between the examples and grammarian-speak. "I am disinclined to recognize my weak mathematical skills, whereas willing to admit my lack of English skills." is not grammatical in formal English, and "whereas" is not a subordinator. It is a failed coordinating conjunction.

Comment: So how come you can put the so-called coordinating conjunction and it's clause *before* the main clause? That's something that coordinators can't do and 'subordinating conjunctions' (aka prepositions) can. Am I winning you round?